# Image height in safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I have a problem with some image in safari. It is working everywhere but not in safari. I've some images on my site but on safari the image's are going way to high.

The website is development.mar-bakker.nl

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="grid wow zoomIn">
                    <figure class="effect-bubba">
                        <img src="assets/images/item-2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="img01"/>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h2>Webshop <span>PC4U</span></h2>
                            <p>Lily likes to play with crayons and pencils</p>
                        </figcaption>           
                    </figure>
                </div>

            </div>
```

And the css is this:

```
    figure.effect-bubba {
    background: #9e5406;
}
figure.effect-bubba img {
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s;
}

figure.effect-bubba:hover img {
    opacity: 0.4;
}

figure.effect-bubba figcaption::before,
figure.effect-bubba figcaption::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 30px;
    content: '';
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
}

figure.effect-bubba figcaption::before {
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0,1);
    transform: scale(0,1);
}

figure.effect-bubba figcaption::after {
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,0);
    transform: scale(1,0);
}

figure.effect-bubba h2 {
    padding-top: 10%;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: transform 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-20px,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,-20px,0);
    color: #fff;
}

figure.effect-bubba p {
    padding: 20px 2.5em;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,20px,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,20px,0);
}

figure.effect-bubba:hover figcaption::before,
figure.effect-bubba:hover figcaption::after {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}

figure.effect-bubba:hover h2,
figure.effect-bubba:hover p {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Can someone help me.

Comment: maybe so? http://jsfiddle.net/a177hjud/

Comment: nope still no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the error! it was by a diffent css element

```
   .grid figure figcaption, .grid figure figcaption > a {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the max-width and min-height definitions in the .grid figure img selector

`.grid figure img {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    /* min-height: 100%; */
    /* max-width: 100%; */
    opacity: 0.8;
    }`